# Why am I getting an error message while trying to code for change?

Tags: java, currency

This is the question: A store clerk wants a program that calculates the exact change to give a customer with the minimum number of bills and coins. You should input the amount of the purchase and the amount of money tendered (given to the clerk) and then output the change required and the number of each bill and coin to make up the change. Remember you want the minimum number of coins and bills in each case.

** Plan out this program first, before writing any code **

A sample run of the program is shown below.

```
Change Making Program
Please enter the total purchase: $1.42
Please enter the amount tendered: $20.00
The change will be: $18.58
To make up this amount you will need:
1 ten-dollar bill
1 five-dollar bill
1 two-dollar coin
1 loonie
2 quarters
1 nickel
3 pennies
Thank you for using the Change Making Program
```

This is what I have so far:

```
package defaultpackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ChangeMaker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        System.out.print("Please enter the total of your purchase: $");
        double total = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
        
        System.out.print("Please enter the amount of money tendered: $");
        double tendered = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
        
        double change = tendered - total;
        
        System.out.print("Your change is: $" +change);
    
        if (change > 99.99)
        {
            double hundreds = (change - (change % 100)) / 100;
            System.out.print("Hundred-dollar bills: " + hundreds);
            change = change - (hundreds * 100);
        }
        if (change > 49.99)
        {
            double fifties = (change - (change % 50)) / 50;
            System.out.print("Fifty-dollar bills: " + fifties);
            change = change - (fifties * 50);
        }
        if (change > 19.99)
        {
            double twenties = (change - (change % 20)) / 20;
            System.out.print("Twenty-dollar bills: " + twenties);
            change = change - (twenties * 20);
        }
        if (change > 9.99)
        {
            double tens = (change - (change % 10)) / 10;
            System.out.print("Ten-dollar bills: " + tens);
            change = change - (tens * 10);
        }
        if (change > 4.99)
        {
            double fives = (change - (change % 5)) / 5;
            System.out.print("Five-dollar bills: " + fives);
            change = change - (fives * 5);
        }
        if (change > 1.99)
        {
            double toonies = (change - (change % 2)) / 2;
            System.out.print("Toonies: " + toonies);
            change = change - (toonies * 2);
        }
        if (change > 0.99)
        {
            double loonies = (change - (change % 1)) / 1;
            System.out.print("Loonies: " + loonies);
            change = change - (loonies * 1);
        }
        if (change > 0.24)
        {
            double quarters = (change - (change % 0.25)) / 0.25;
            System.out.print("Quarters: " + quarters);
            change = change - (quarters * 0.25);
        }
        if (change > 0.09)
        {
            double dimes = (change - (change % 0.1)) / 0.1;
            System.out.print("Dimes: " + dimes);
            change = change - (dimes * 0.1);
        }
        if (change > 0.04)
        {
            double nickles = (change - (change % 0.05)) / 0.05;
            System.out.print("Nickles: " + nickles);
            change = change - (nickles * 0.05);
        }
        if (change > 0)
        {
            double pennies = (change - (change % 0.1)) / 0.1;
            System.out.print("Pennies : " + pennies);
            change = change - (pennies * 0.1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: please edit the question and show complete stack trace if there is one

Comment: Note: `Integer.parseInt` can only parse ints (whole numbers). If you're expecting to be able to enter dollars and pennies, you'd need to use e.g. `Double.parseDouble`.

Comment: Please enter the total of your purchase: $14.29
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "14.29"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
 at defaultpackage.ChangeMaker.main(ChangeMaker.java:12)

Comment: Your code expects an integer input, but you have entered 14.29.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a lot Andy Turner

Comment: Note: You can use `>=` instead of checking `> x.99`

Answer (score 0):

I have overseen the `parseInt` problem, but there is still another problem:

```
pennies = (change - (change % 0.1)) / 0.1;
...
change = change - (pennies * 0.1);
```

should be `0.01` instead of `0.1` - or just use what is left in `change`.

Advice: do not use `double` for money - lots of problems with rounding! (chances of change being short by one penny)
either use `int`/ `long` to represent cents, or
use `BigDecimal`

Note `(change - (change % 100)) / 100` is basically the same as `(int)(change / 100)` - casting to `int` *removes* all decimals

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the problem you present.  It produces exactly the desired output.

The code uses integer math to avoid the precision problems you will inevitably have when using floating point values to represent dollar amounts.  To do this, input values are multiplied by 100 and treated as cents. When printing out dollar amounts, we divide by 100 to represent the values in dollars.

Another feature of this code is that it is data-driven.  Rather than duplicate the logic for removing each denomination over and over, a table provides the information about each denomination, and then there is only one block of code that is run in a loop to deal with each denomination.  The code deals with properly pluralizing each denomination name when appropriate, including the special case for "pennies".

```
package defaultpackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

class Denomination {
    public Denomination(int value, String name, String pluralName) {
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
        this.pluralName = pluralName;
    }

    public Denomination(int value, String name) {
        this(value, name, null);
    }

    String getDescription(int count) {
        String desc = this.name;
        if (count > 1)
            if (pluralName == null)
                desc += 's';
            else
                desc = pluralName;
        return desc;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private final int value;
    private final String name;
    private final String pluralName;
}

class ChangeMaker {

    private static final List<Denomination> denominations = List.of(
            new Denomination(10000, "one-hundred-dollar bill"),
            new Denomination(5000, "fifty-dollar bill"),
            new Denomination(2000, "twenty-dollar bill"),
            new Denomination(1000, "ten-dollar bill"),
            new Denomination(500, "five-dollar bill"),
            new Denomination(200, "two-dollar coin"),
            new Denomination(100, "loonie"),
            new Denomination(25, "quarter"),
            new Denomination(10, "dime"),
            new Denomination(5, "nickel"),
            new Denomination(1, "penny", "pennies")
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Change Making Program");
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Please enter the total purchase: $");
        int total = (int)(Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine()) * 100);

        System.out.print("Please enter the amount tendered: $");
        int tendered = (int)(Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine()) * 100);

        int change = tendered - total;

        System.out.printf("The change will be: $%.2f\n", change / 100.0);
        System.out.println("To make up this amount you will need:");

        for (Denomination denom: denominations) {
            if (change == 0)
                break;
            if (change >= denom.getValue()) {
                int count = change / denom.getValue();
                if (count > 0) {
                    change = change - denom.getValue() * count;
                    System.out.printf("%d %s\n", count, denom.getDescription(count));
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you for using the Change Making Program");
    }
}
```

Sample Run:

```
Change Making Program
Please enter the total purchase: $1.42
Please enter the amount tendered: $20.00
The change will be: $18.58
To make up this amount you will need:
1 ten-dollar bill
1 five-dollar bill
1 two-dollar coin
1 loonie
2 quarters
1 nickel
3 pennies
Thank you for using the Change Making Program
```

If the OP is asking this question to do a homework assignment, then I expect that this answer may be "too good".  It may be using techniques not yet studied in class.  Even if the OP could submit this as-is, I would encourage them to not do so.  Instead, I'd suggest that they study this example, learn from it, and then incorporate what is learned into their own solution as appropriate.  I encourage them to ask questions about the example, which I'd be happy to answer.